# Format Date to iOS from DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, objective-c, ios

I receive a date in the format below from a json file. Im not sure but i think its formatted by DataContractJsonSerializer Class in the .Net framework. The date looks like this

```
    \/Date(1255993200000+0100)\/
```

I was wondering if anyone would know how i would convert this into normal dates on iOS or if i have to do anything to change it.

Thanks,

Comment: date seems to be invalid

Comment: It's valid - this is actually Tue Oct 20 2009 01:00:00 in terms of seconds since 1970

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
-(NSDate*)mfDateFromDotNetJSONString:(NSString *)string
{
    static NSRegularExpression *dateRegEx = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateRegEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^\\/date\\((-?\\d++)(?:([+-])(\\d{2})(\\d{2}))?\\)\\/$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    });
    NSTextCheckingResult *regexResult = [dateRegEx firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if (regexResult)
    {
        // milliseconds
        NSTimeInterval seconds = [[string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:1]] doubleValue] / 1000.0;
        // timezone offset
        if ([regexResult rangeAtIndex:2].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *sign = [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:2]];
            // hours
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:3]]] doubleValue] * 60.0 * 60.0;
            // minutes
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:4]]] doubleValue] * 60.0;
        }

        return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

and pass string using

`[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` to this function

This helped for me and hope it helps you